# How do I latch a loop on with one button press and end the loop with another button press in C# Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to have a process run continuously starting when one button (button A) is pressed until another button (button B) is pressed in a C# windows forms application, but I am unable to find a good way to do so.

The idea is to create a program that will access various data tags on an OPC UA server and read the data from those tags continuously as a sort of monitoring system. Since I have functions built in to swap the server's URL and the tags to monitor from the application, I need the monitoring loop to be able to be turned on with a button press and off with a separate a button press.

Does anyone have any good suggestions?

I've tried creating a clock and an event handler to trigger a function when the clock reached the designated time count, but I was unable to get the event handler to run continuously (ironically).

Comment: Yes, add a timer to your winform.

Comment: In the bigger picture, it looks like you want to write a Windows service and start / stop it.

Comment: As suggested, the standard [WinForms Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) should do the trick. In the ToolBox, you'll find it in the bottom of the `Components` section. Just drag one onto your form, set it's Interval property to how often you want it to fire, then handle the Tick event. You can turn it on/off using the Enabled property, or by calling the Start()/Stop() methods....

Comment: How are you doing the monitoring? Is it based on a single timer, on a schedule set per tag, as the result of a change in the monitored values the causes an event? One other thing you might consider is to use an `async`/`await` approach with a `CancellationToken`

Comment: The classic approach to this problem (monitoring OPC-style data (and/or control systems)) is to do the monitoring in a separate thread (or even a separate process) and then provide an inter-thread (or inter-process) mechanism for controlling the monitor work. An `async`-ish solution _may_ be more elegant and lighter-weight

Comment: [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) - I think this link will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

When you're reading data from a server and there is uncertainty about how long a query might take, one way to achieve your objective is by passing a `CancellationToken` into a loop that performs the work (taking however long it takes) and then applying the delay between executions of the work. This way there's no danger of issuing a new request before the prior task completes. Here's a basic scheme to do this.

As described in your question, the UI design uses one button to start the loop, and the other to cancel.

[image: demo]

###### UI setup

```cs
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonStart.Click += async(sender, e) => 
        {
            buttonStart.Enabled = false;
            buttonStop.Enabled = true;
            await localCancelTimer();
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _pollingTask = ExecPolling(_cts.Token);
        };
        buttonStop.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                UseWaitCursor = true;
                buttonStop.Enabled = false;
                await localCancelTimer();
                buttonStart.Enabled = true;
            }
            finally
            {
                UseWaitCursor = false;
            }
        };
        async Task localCancelTimer()
        {
            if (_cts is not null && _pollingTask is not null && !_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _cts.Cancel();
                await _pollingTask;
                _cts.Dispose();
            }
        }
        foreach (var button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            button.EnabledChanged += (sender, e) => 
                button.BackColor = button.Enabled ? Color.LightGreen : BackColor;
        }
    }
    CancellationTokenSource? _cts = null;
    Task? _pollingTask = null;
```

###### Timer Loop

```cs
    async Task ExecPolling(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var ping = new Ping();
        while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync("ivsoftware.net");
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
                    richTextBox.AppendText(
                        $"[{DateTime.Now}] ONLINE ivsoftware.net @ {reply.RoundtripTime}ms{Environment.NewLine}");
                }
                else
                {
                    richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                    richTextBox.AppendText($"[{DateTime.Now}] FAILED ivsoftware.net: {reply.Status}{Environment.NewLine}");
                }
                richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
                await Task.Delay(1000, token);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                richTextBox.AppendText($"[{DateTime.Now}] Operation cancelled.{Environment.NewLine}");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/cancelable-periodic-timer-loop.git)